# Override computed property in Ember 4 adapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In the "new" class style of Ember / JavaScript (at least new to me), I am having trouble adapting old tutorials to set a computed property in my `JSONAPIAdapter`.

```
export default class ApplicationAdapter extends JSONAPIAdapter {
  @service session;

  headers: computed('session.isAuthenticated', 'session.data.authenticated.token', function() {
    if (this.session.isAuthenticated) {
      return {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${ this.session.data.authenticated.token }`,
```

Results in

```
$TMPDIR/embroider/b3d2a6/adapters/application.js/application.js: Unexpected token (8:9)

   6 |   @service session;
   7 |
>  8 |   headers: computed('session.isAuthenticated', 'session.data.authenticated.token', function() {
```

The docs ( https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/4.3/classes/JSONAPIAdapter/properties/headers?anchor=headers ) imply that this should work, but I think the `@service session` line is messing things up.

What is the correct way to set the `headers` property an Ember 4 class in 2022?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure exactly what error you're seeing, but you should be able to replace this with a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

```js
get headers() {
  if (this.session.isAuthenticated) {
    return {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${ this.session.data.authenticated.token }
    }
  }
}
```

You can see a working example [in our addapter](https://github.com/ilios/common/blob/master/addon/adapters/ilios.js)

Comment: Worked like a charm. So, where I see `property: function()` in old Ember tutorials I should replace with `get property()` ? One last question: does the example code in the link look wrong to you since it references `headers: computed(function()...` ?

Comment: Yes, almost everywhere that will work. You can also use the syntax you found in the docs you linked, but you shouldn't declare each item used, just `computed(function()`. There is some more information in [the autoracking guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/in-depth-topics/autotracking-in-depth/)